# Rodeo permission denied

Tags: python, rodeo

When i tried to run rodeo (python IDE) in linux Mint, i've got an error:

```
$python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/Rodeo/resources/app/node/kernels/python/start_kernel.py", line 18, in <module>
    raise Exception('Jupyter is not installed')
Exception: Jupyter is not installed
* Jupyter is not installed
```

But when i print `python` from terminal, i launch anaconda

```
 ~ $ python
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:42:40) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>>
```

Also i tried to set direct path to python, rodeo said "Permission denied"

How can i fix this?

**UPD.**
This error occurs only when i run Rodeo from Docky or panel bar. When i run it from Terminal via `/opt/Rodeo/rodeo` it works well

Comment: Have you tried `pip install --user jupyter` ? It installs a copy just for your user.

Comment: I am newbie in linux, but i think i am the only user.

Comment: Just try the above, and if it doesn't work, try launching with `sudo`.

Comment: If you already have an environment working but missing Jupyter you want to use run:  conda install -n spatial_env jupyter

Comment: try with sudo as well